# How can I prevent AgGrid range selection on right-click?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using AgGrid Enterprise and want to bring up a context menu on right-click without changing the current range selection. I've tried every event listener I can think of and there doesn't seem to be a way to suppress this behavior.

quite honestly, I think the behavior is a bug itself. A right-click/alt-click to bringing up the context menu is NOT signaling a user intention to select the range. But, I'd be happy if I could just find any kind of workaround!

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the fact that on right click you get a single cell range selection then this is a workaround for this.

Implement the `getContextMenuItems` callback and return the default items to not impact the context menu. However, you can then implement some logic based on the current `cellRanges` to know whether to clear the range selection or not.

```
function getContextMenuItems(
  params: GetContextMenuItemsParams
): (string | MenuItemDef)[] {
  const cellRanges = params.api.getCellRanges();
  // Rough check for a single cell range
  if (
    cellRanges.length === 1 &&
    cellRanges[0].startRow == cellRanges[0].endRow &&
    cellRanges[0].columns.length == 1
  ) {
    params.api.clearRangeSelection();
  }

  return params.defaultItems;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/MX82ttjQLMy5hlHI?open=main.ts